# sql server querying values in upper case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a sql server table which has values in upper case and it doesn't return anything. 
For example,

Table structure,

```
ID  Fruit
--  ------
1   APPLE ONE
2   ORANGE TWO
3   PEAR THREE

Select * from Fruits where fruit = 'APPLE ONE'
```

Does not return anything. But if i change it to "apple one" in the database  and change the query to

```
Select * from Fruits where fruit = 'apple one'
```

it works.

how do u get this work with upper case data ?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't some extra spaces there?

Comment: I don't really believe your queries here because SQL does not use double quotes.

Comment: what collation are you using?

Comment: @Hogan - It will interpret double quoted items as string literals if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is off.

Comment: The data `APPLE ONE` will match the string literal `APPLE ONE` in every collation. So one of them must be different from what you have shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UPPER or LOWER function.  Like this:

```
Select * from Fruits where UPPER(fruit) = 'APPLE ONE'
```

Also like op. will ignore case:

```
Select * from Fruits where fruit like 'APPLE ONE'
```

Comment: @Dd2 - You really think someone with this question has added an index to a column?

Comment: I wonder if the OP has 3 pears or he's concatenating his ID with the name... in english.

Comment: = normally isn't case sensitive either.

Comment: @BlackICE I was going to answer with collation, but felt that it wasn't worth my time to explain it.

Comment: Updated the double quote issue

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your column is set to the correct collation. Or you can specify the collation in your query directly.

Collations with CI are Case Insensitive. This will return your 'apple one' record:

```
select 'CI', * from table1
where myfield = 'apple one' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

This will not return your 'apple one' record because it is CS (case sensitive):

```
select 'CS', * from table1
where myfield = 'apple one' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

If all your queries use the same collation for this column, it's best to set it on the column. If all your queries use the same collation on all columns, it's best to set it on the database itself as a default.

Eg. Setting it for the column:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([myfield] varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
;
```

Comment: In every collation (including binary and case sensitive) if the data is `APPLE ONE` and the `WHERE` clause is looking for `APPLE ONE` then the row should be returned though.

Answer (score -1):

In these cases, the best things is to convert both sides of EQUAL oeprator to either UPPER or LOWER

```
Select * from Fruits where UPPER(fruit) = UPPER('apple one')
```

or

```
Select * from Fruits where LOWER(fruit) = LOWER(apple one')
```